# JS Framework - Field Labels / Text

Tags: jquery, json, backbone.js, properties

I am developing an app using Backbone and jQuery and I have a question about where to put things like labels for form fields, page titles, button texts, etc.

I'm guessing that these should be externalized into some sort of property file, especially to support i18n, but I am unable to find any good documentation on what is best practice for this.

In the past with Java apps and JSPs, we stored things like this in a .properties file.  Should I use the same concept and put these things in JSON file(s) and then issue an XHR request to get the file and plug them in that way?

Basically, I'm looking for a best practice for this sort of thing when developing an app using a client/UI framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create language files as objects, if you are using require for example:

`locale/en_gb.js`

```
define({
    buttons: {
        ok: 'Ok',
        error: 'Error',
        prompts: {
            saveChanges: 'You have unsaved changes. Would you like to save them?',
            quit: 'Are you sure you want to quit?'
        }
    },

    pages: {
        home: 'Home'
        contact: 'Contact'
    }
});
```

You have such locale files for different languages.

In your extended Views you can create some methods like this:

```
localeBase: null,
currentLocale: null,

loadLocale: function(localeName) {
    require('locale/'+localeName, function(Locale) {
        this.currentLocale = Locale;
    });
},

l: function(lookupStr) {
    // Lookup 'lookupStr' in 'this.currentLocale'
}
```

The `l` method take `.` annotated lookup strings like:

`"pages.home"` returns `"Home"`

Or if `localeBase` is set to something like:

`"buttons"`

Then if the string starts with a `.`:

`".prompts.quit"`

It will lookup relative to `localeBase` (if it doesn't start with dot lookup from beginning AKA absolute lookup).

Note that `localeBase` is not a necessary concept it depends on your preference.

In your `View` `render` method, you pass the view as the `template context`:

```
var html = myTemplateRenderer_Function(this);
this.el.html(html);
```

Your template file then has access to the `l` method to so you can do stuff like:

```
<button value="<%= l('buttons.ok') %>" />
```